# Which Monero release should be used on Asus Tinker Board?

Tags: release-naming

I noticed there are two ARM releases, v7 and v8, but I couldn't find what version is the Tinker Board.
Which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tinker Board uses a [Rockchip RK3288](https://www.asus.com/Single-Board-Computer/Tinker-Board/), which uses an ARM Cortex-A17. According to [Wikipedia, that chip implements the ARMv7-A architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A17).